# Spotfire- Sum Specific Values Within A Repeated Values Column

Tags: spotfire

This question will be similar to others, but different in the sense that I need to select 2 distinct values to be summed, instead of all column values. I've tried several Over/Intersect statements and can't seem to get the right value. I've attached a screenshot of the data that I have:
[image: Table]

In the Table, you can see that I have a "Month Batch" and "PKG Name" that makes the values specific. I'd really like my "Norm Sum" column to take one of the max values from each "Month Batch" and "PKG Name" and sum them. The "Goal" column is what I'd like to see.
I've tried to do Sum( max([!] over (intersect([Month Batch], [PKG Name])) but this gives me a wild value. I've tried to set up case statements in the "Norm 1", "Norm 2", and "Norm 3" columns, but summing the max of those columns over their intersections didn't work either. 
Maybe I'm having a brain block, but this isn't coming to me easily. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
Sum(case when Rank([!],"desc","ties.method=first",[Month Batch],[PKG Name])=1 then [!] end)
```

Comment: Just tried using this and it unfortunately didn't work. I think this formula sums all values within each Month Batch/PKG Name and it isn't picking out the max values of each Month Batch/PKG Name to sum. The value is a very large number... Any other ideas? I need it to only select 1 value of the max of each and sum those two values together.

Comment: Are the values in the month batch column strings or dates?

Comment: They're Strings... like "Jan 2022"